# Query in QuickSort Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

'''

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int *low, int *high){
    int temp = *low;
    *low = *high;
    *high = temp;
}
void printarr(int arr[], int n){
    for(int i=0; i< n; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high){
    int i = low-1;
    int pivot = arr[high];
    for(int j=low; j<high; j++){
        if(arr[j]<=pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    printarr(arr, high);
    swap(&arr[i+1], &arr[high]);
    return (i+1);
}
void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high){
    if(low < high){
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high);
        quickSort(arr, low, pi-1);
        quickSort(arr, pi+1, high);
    }
}
int main(){
    int arr[] = {8, 7, 6, 1, 0, 9, 2};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    quickSort(arr, 0, size-1);
    printarr(arr, size);
}
```

'''

Hi my doubt is that

```
int partition(int arr[], int low, int high){
    int i = low-1;
    int pivot = arr[high];
    for(int j=low; j<high; j++){
        if(arr[j]<=pivot){
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    printarr(arr, high);
    swap(&arr[i+1], &arr[high]);
    return (i+1);
}
```

In this for loop why are we taking 'j' as 'i'? and by the way 'i' would be -1 in the first iteration. Won't the compiler gives an error for arr[-1]? I'm sorry if it feels silly doubt for you but i don't understand this part.

Comment: You can [edit] your question with additional or fixed informaiton at any time, even without a note that you have edited it.

Comment: *Won't the compiler gives an error for arr[-1]* --  Negative subscripts are not compiler errors.  C++ does not check these things -- It's your responsibility to make sure the subscript is within bounds.